# Organizing filters in a Rails 4 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, code-organization

I have a small code organization problem in a Rails 4 app.

Let's say that we have `Users`. Every user can have several `Accounts`.

if I wanted to have a `show` action in the `UsersController`, I would probably have such a filter as:

```
before_filter :user_exists? only: :show

...

def user_exists
    @user = User.find_by id: params[:id]
    redirect_to :back, flash: { alert: "That user does not exist." } if !@user
end
```

Said filter would live probably in the `UsersController` since it makes sense, semantically speaking, to organize it there. Right?

So now let's say that I want to create an account, which of course uses the action `create` in the `AccountsController`. I want to make sure that I dont create an account for a user that no longer exists. (For instance, between the time that the user clicked "Create account" and the time he submitted the form, the user could have been deleted). So the same filter would be applied:

```
before_filter :user_exists? only: :create
```

My conundrum lies here:

Where should now live the filter?

**Option #1:** We move the filter to the ApplicationController.

This would work, but it has the disadvantage of de-organize my code. If I start taking this technique every time I stomp on this problem (and given Model relationships, this can happen quite often), I would end up with a code quite "spread". Not truly desirable.

**Option #2:** We duplicate the filter in both controllers. the disadvantage here is clear. Code harder to maintain. Duplicated code is bad.

Is there an **Option #3**? Is there a Rails way to solve this problem cleaner?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "We want to make sure that we do not create an account for a user that no longer exists"

Answer (score 1):

You could add this filter to a `module` and mix it in your controllers.

```
module UserExists

  def self.included(base)
    base.before_filter :user_exists? only: :create
  end

  def user_exists
    @user = User.find_by id: params[:id]
    redirect_to :back, flash: { alert: "That user does not exist." } if !@user
  end

end
```

The `self.included` is called when you mix it in your classes.

```
class users_controller
  include UserExists
```

Comment: A little verbose, for a Rails 4 app, but I guess that works. I will wait to see if someone else comes up with something more elegant. Thanks!

Comment: please dont it as argument, I'm just beginner, i want to ask this for my knowledge, what is the difference between putting this method in module and including that module everywhere and adding this method to application controller and calling that in your sub controllers. atleast there we have the benefit of adding this filter to as many actions as i want.?  might be different controllers want this filter to be run for different actions.

Comment: @Athar If you put a `filter` in you `application_controller`, it would trigger in every controller that inherits from it. If you put it on a module, and then mix this module in a few controllers, the `filter` will only trigger in these mixed-in controllers.  The nature of `filters` is that they are not callable. They are invoked automatically, thus why you need to put it on a module.

Comment: @Dbugger That's ok, just keep in mind that is a perfect scenario for mix in some modules.

Comment: @MurifoX Thank you.:)